# Why are subsequent calls to a Kotlin function faster in Android apps?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin

I'm trying to compare performance of Kotlin and C++ in Android environment by implementing certain algorithms in both languages, running them with identical input data, and comparing execution times. However, while results for C++ functions are largely consistent in subsequent calls, this is not the case in Kotlin.

For example, here are the execution times in milliseconds for 5 subsequent calls to the function performing bubble sort in C++:

```
for length=100000 : 43031;
for length=100000 : 43023;
for length=100000 : 43046;
for length=100000 : 43053;
for length=100000 : 43014;
```

And here are the times for 5 subsequent calls to the function performing the same operation in Kotlin:

```
for length=100000 : 41578;
for length=100000 : 16331;
for length=100000 : 16351;
for length=100000 : 16328;
for length=100000 : 16325;
```

Both functions take a freshly created instance of IntArray provided by Kotlin's built-in generateSequence function (they're created according to the same algorithm everytime to ensure repeatability). Just in case, here's the code in Kotlin:

```
fun ktBubbleSort(numbers: IntArray): IntArray {
    for (pass in 0 until (numbers.size - 1)) {
        // A single pass of bubble sort
        for (currentPosition in 0 until (numbers.size - pass - 1)) {
            // This is a single step
            if (numbers[currentPosition] > numbers[currentPosition + 1]) {
                val tmp = numbers[currentPosition]
                numbers[currentPosition] = numbers[currentPosition + 1]
                numbers[currentPosition + 1] = tmp
            }
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

As we can see, subsequent executions of Kotlin function are much shorter than the first one. The situation persists until the app is restarted.

What's the cause of this, and is it possible to somehow alter this behaviour without being forced to restart the app each time?

Comment: Kotlin might be JIT compiled, so it might be choosing to compile hot spots in your code at runtime, which would make later iterations faster.

Comment: This would certainly be absolutely normal and expected on a JVM (for JIT reasons).  On Android, I'd tend to expect it might have to do with classes and code getting loaded.

Comment: Disabling JIT through ADB had changed the results dramatically. Thanks for the tips!